# Why import instruction is not executed into python Process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, runpy

I'm looking for a solution to do multiprocessing for running script.
I have a function which launches 4 process, and each process executes a script through `runpy.run_path()` and I get return back.

Example :

```
def valorise(product, dico_valo):
    res = runpy.run_path(product +"/PyScript.py", run_name="__main__")
    dico_valo[product] = res["ret"]

def f(mutex,l,dico):
    while len(l)!= 0:
        mutex.acquire()
        product = l.pop(0)
        mutex.release()
        p = Process(target=valorise, args=(product,dico))
        p.start()
        p.join()

def run_parallel_computations(valuationDate, list_scripts):
    if len(product_list)>0:
        print '\n\nPARALLEL COMPUTATIONS BEGIN..........\n\n'
        manager = Manager()
        l = manager.list(list_scripts)
        dico = manager.dict()
        mutex = Lock()
        p1 = Process(target=f, args=(mutex,l,dico), name="script1")
        p2 = Process(target=f, args=(mutex,l,dico), name="script2")
        p3 = Process(target=f, args=(mutex,l,dico), name="script3")
        p4 = Process(target=f, args=(mutex,l,dico), name="script4")
        p1.start()        
        p2.start()
        p3.start()
        p4.start()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()
        p3.join()
        p4.join()
        dico_isin = {}
        for i in iter(dico.keys()):
            dico_isin[i] = dico[i]
        return dico
        print '\n\nPARALLEL COMPUTATIONS END..........'
    else:
        print '\n\nNOTHING TO PRICE !'
```

In every PyScript.py, I import a library and each script has to import again it. However, in this case, it doesn't work as I want and I don't understand why. My library is imported once during the first process and the same "import" is used in the other processes.
Could you help me ?

Thank you !

Comment: What do you mean - "it doesn't work". Does your pc spontaneously combust, or create blackholes, or generate error messages ? I think we will need more to go on. It could be something as simple as a sys.path issue - but who knows ?

Comment: Sorry, I edited. "My library is imported once during the first process and the same "import" is used in the other processes." In this library, I have global variables and I want to reset them during each "runpy.run_path". (Of course, I cannot edit this library...)

Comment: Are you expecting these global variables to be shared between the processes since all processes import the same library module?  If you are then that won't happen - you will need to use a different system (shared memory for is

Comment: No, the opposite. I expected each process have their own global variables but it is not the case. As though I was using `os.system()` to run my script.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the case in multiprocessing (but looks like it is).
When you will try to import something more than once (ie. `import re` in most of your modules), Python will not 'reimport' it. As it will see it in modules already imported and will skip it.

To force reloading you can try [reload(module_name)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) (it can not reload import of single class/method from module, you can reload whole module or nothing)

Comment: It's strange, but in the case of multiprocessing, Python imports once. So my global variables in the library are shared and I don't want that. Each process needs to have their own global variables. I could use `reload` but im lookin for a more elegant solution. To sum up, I would like to have the same behavior than I am using `os.system()`

Comment: Would it be possible to use classes (instances) to encapsulate variables in it, rather than using global variables?

Comment: Yes it would be possible but we cannot edit the sources of the library